# Three people want to personally meet each other as fast as possible: optimization problem.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, optimization, puzzle

**Problem:** Three people want to be all gathered at the same place, and they want it to happen as soon as possible. Where should they head to?

P.S. Assume they all travel with the same speed. Think of the people as points in a plane. A person can stop and wait.

**Remarks:**

- One possible approach is for the person in the middle to remain still and the others to head towards he/she. This is simple, but is not optimal in the general case.
- If they are all on a straight line or on a circle the problem should be easier, but it's still not the general case and I don't know if solving for these special cases will shed light on the general one.

**Note:** I invented this problem by myself, but maybe it was already discussed/solved somewhere, if this is the case please point some reference(s).

Comment: Technically, they are always either on a straight line or on a circle!

Comment: LOL, you are right! Haha, I was tired after thinking too much and almost sleeping when I wrote this, ofc since it's 3 points there is always a circle that passes through them or they are collinear! Thanks. I will not edit the question because I'm going to sleep now and it's a fun thing on the question :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  You are trying to find a point which minimises the maximum distance to the given points / people.  In general, this would be the centre of the smallest "covering circle" for the points.

In the case of three points, this would then be either the circumcentre or the midpoint of the longest side...

For more, you may want to search for "minimax facility location" problem.

Comment: I don't think the circumcenter gives the solution in general.  For example if an obtuse triangle is formed, you'd get a better result if you took the midpoint of the longest side.  E.g., if the three points (people) were located at $(-5,0)$, $(5,0)$, and $(7,2)$, then the circumcenter is at $(0,7)$, a distance of $\sqrt{74}$ from each point.  On the other hand the midpoint of the long side is $(1,1)$, with distances to the three points being $\sqrt{37}$, $\sqrt{17}$, and $\sqrt{37}$ respectively, all strictly less than the distance to the circumcenter.

Comment: @paw88789 Youre right.  Will modify it.

Comment: To summarise: the meeting point is the circumcentre for acute triangles, and the mid-point of the longest side for obtuse triangles.

Comment: @TonyK Yes. For right triangle, both being the same. For collinear points, the midpoint of the longest segment.